# Позиционирование блока относительно фона

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

Есть нетривиальная задача.

```css
html, body, .bg-cover {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-cover {
  background-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  height: 10.416666666666668vw;
  width: 18.75vw;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 29.947916666666668vw;
  top: 24vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-cover">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Фоновое изображение:

[image: фон]

Необходимо позиционировать `element` в белой области фона TV, таким образом, чтобы не нарушалось взаимное расположение фона и блока `element`.

Проблема в том, что при разных разрешениях экрана фон масштабируется по разному. 
Может как-то можно получать позицию пикселя на фоне через `js` и относительно этого играть?

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с подобной проблемой?

Comment: @Air, вероятно, о телевизоре на фото.

Comment: Важно, является ли фон фоном всего окна или это какой-то элемент.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я уже сообразил после твоей правки))))  Кстати вчера вроде видел подобный вопрос

Comment: @Meetromb Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! Первый вопрос и сразу на уровне.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Решение адаптивно,  работает во всех браузерах, включая `Edge`.**

Чтобы два блока с изображениями,- в вашем случае картинка комнаты и фон-изображение на TV, согласованно меняли свои пропорции и не нарушалось при этом взаимное позиционирование, необходимо разместить оба изображения внутри блока `SVG`

```css
<style>
html, body, .bg-cover {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.element {
width:100%; 
height:100%;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="bg-cover">
  <div class="element">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1776 943">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <image xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/keh4g.jpg" x="537" y="212" width="19.1%" height="19.1%" />
  </svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

Интересно сделать изображение на TV меняющееся  динамически. Идея понятна,- нужно спрятать спрайт с изображениями под картинку спальни и прокручивать спрайт, чтобы сквозь вырез экрана TV был виден спрайт.
Пробовал достаточно долго варианты с масками, с клипами, комбинированные способы, но не получилось. Отверстие в экране TV образуется, но сквозь него спрайта не видно.

Есть ли у кого идеи, как сделать это?

**Update**
Решение  динамической смены изображений - [Имитация смены изображений на экране TV](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/794050/28748)

Comment: Гениально....)))))

Comment: Даже не сомневался)

Comment: @Meetromb К сожалению хорошая литература об SVG только на английском.На русском я встречал только две стоящие книги: 1.Вадим  Дунаев - Основы SVG и  перевод J. David Eisenberg - SVG Essentials

Answer (score 3):

`svg` , конечно, сильная технология, но позиционирование элементов на svg холсте мало отличается от абсолютного позиционирования в `css`. Для разнообразия предложу такой вариант(вместо гифки можно, например, поставить видео).
**P.S.** Интересно было бы посмотреть решение с обрезкой фоновой картинки(`cover`). Все таки и в моём варианте, и в решении Alexandr_TT пропорции фона сохраняются.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
.room{
  position:relative;
}
.room__bg{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.room__tv{
  position:absolute;
  top:21.7%;
  left:30.15%;
  width:19.3%;
  height:20.2%;
  background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif/220px-Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif) no-repeat center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="room">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg" class="room__bg" alt="" />
  <div class="room__tv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну так не договаривались гифки, видео вставлять :)))  Ответ хороший, ловите плюс Вам надо было ответ разместить в соседнем топике = Имитация смены изображений на экране TV - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/794050/28748  Можно здесь оставить ответ и там ответить с добавлением видео на экран TV

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать ещё проще по топорному если не критичен размер изображений либо разрешение не слишком высоко. Берёте фон и загружаете в фотошоп, добавляете нужный элемент другим слоем и позиционируете, скрываете фон и сохраняете картинку с элементом. получаем и фон и элемент одинакового размера, у элемента соответственно фон прозрачный. в вёрстке размещаете оба блока друг над другом , делаете `background-size:cover;background-position: 50% 50%;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;` и всё.

Comment: работающий код разместите, пожалуйста в снипет. чтобы проверить вашу версию на работоспособность и главное адаптивность