# Имитация смены изображений на экране TV

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Идея данного вопроса возникла по мотивам ответа  -
["Позиционирование блока относительно фона"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781196/28748)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Эту картинку можно использовать для ответа*

В том ответе удалось поместить статичную картинку на экран TV и сделать её адаптивной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но хочется большей реалистичности, то есть сделать картинку живой, с анимацией смены изображений на экране TV.

*Вопрос, как сделать это.*

Понятно, что нужно, подложить под экран TV слайдер с картинками. И маской или `clipPath` вырезать область подобную экрану TV. Перепробовал несколько вариантов решения с масками, но ни один не сработал.

Допустимо применение любой техники для реализации анимации и адаптивности приложения: `svg`, `css`, `javascript` или все техники вместе.

Решение должно быть адаптивно и работать во всех современных браузерах, кроме IE, так как он не дружит с анимацией по определению.

Это учебный вопрос-пример, но он дополнительно имеет и практическое применение. Допускается любое количество ответов, все будут отмечены.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Еще вариант, просто работа с `opacity`, можно конечно плавности добавить, но вроде телевизоры плавно не переключаются)))

```js
let show = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
var count = 0;
(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (count >= show.length) {
      count = 0;
    }
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.show')].forEach(s => {
      s.style.opacity = '0';
    })
    document.querySelectorAll('.show')[count++].style.opacity = '1';
  }, 3111);
})();
```

```css
*,
* ::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ns {
  touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.show {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-cover">
    <div class="element">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 1776 943">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <image style="opacity: 1"  class="show" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/keh4g.jpg" x="537" y="212" width="19.1%" height="19.1%" />
  <image  class="show" xlink:href="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2015/_A_small_castle_on_the_cliff_above_the_sea__Crimea_099190_.jpg" x="537" y="212" width="19.1%" height="19.1%" />
  <image  class="show" xlink:href="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/753/371608-svetik.jpg" x="537" y="212" width="19.1%" height="19.1%" />
  <image  class="show" xlink:href="https://storge.pic2.me/c/1360x800/454/5848714f87bf5.jpg" x="537" y="212" width="19.1%" height="19.1%" />
  <image  class="show" xlink:href="http://st.gdefon.com/wallpapers_original/s/237948_leto_-derevya_-zelen_-solnce_-nebo_-les_2560x1600_(www.GdeFon.ru).jpg" x="537" y="212" width="19.1%" height="19.1%" />
  </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Второй вариант с изменением  значения атрибута `'xlink:href`

```js
var pic = [
  'http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2015/_A_small_castle_on_the_cliff_above_the_sea__Crimea_099190_.jpg',
  'https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/753/371608-svetik.jpg',
  'https://storge.pic2.me/c/1360x800/454/5848714f87bf5.jpg',
  'http://st.gdefon.com/wallpapers_original/s/237948_leto_-derevya_-zelen_-solnce_-nebo_-les_2560x1600_(www.GdeFon.ru).jpg'
];



let show = document.getElementById('show');
var count = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  let showAttr = show.getAttribute('xlink:href');
  if (count == pic.length) {
    count = 1;
  }
  show.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', pic[count]);

  count++;
}, 3111);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-cover">
    <div class="element">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 1776 943">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <image  id="show" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/keh4g.jpg" x="537" y="212" width="19.1%" height="19.1%" />
 
  </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ещё один замечательный вариант А если попробовать в цикле, с той же opacity поиграть, типа одна картинка затухает, а вторая нарастает Можно вторым вариантом оформить, скорее даже нужно, чтобы 1-ый вариант не пропал

Comment: погоди, я тут кое что еще другою творю, если получиться будет три варианта))))

Answer (score 9):

Могу предложить эффект испорченного телевизора с "нарушенной" строчной и кадровой синхронизацией. В старых версиях эксплорера изображение даже слегка синусоидально изгибалось влево-вправо.

```js
for(i = 0; i < 60; i++){
 var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var kadr = new Image();
 kadr.src = (a == 0 ? "http://opan1.16mb.com/1/img/sboy.jpg" : "http://opan1.16mb.com/1/img/diktor.jpg");
 kadr.style.width = "89px";
 kadr.style.height = "67px";
 tv.appendChild(kadr);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://opan1.16mb.com/1/img/telek.jpg">
<marquee id=tv scrollamount="143" scrolldelay="45" direction="up" width="90" height="67" style="FILTER: wave(add=10,phase=1,freq=2,strength=3);position:absolute;left:45px;top:44px">
</marquee>
```

А если хотите нормальное движущееся изображение, лучше наверно наложить на картинку видео без панели с кнопками, или с панелью, но на задний план фоновой картинки, сделав экран на ней прозрачным.

Comment: Прикольно, надо его  к мастеру нести...  Сто пудов какой-нить транзистор полетел...)))  Стоит (+)...

Answer (score 8):

Вариант с видео

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
.room{
  position:relative;
}
.room__bg{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.room__tv{
  position:absolute;
  top:21.7%;
  left:30.15%;
  width:19.3%;
  height:20.2%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="room">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg" class="room__bg" alt="" />
  <video class="room__tv" src="https://sample-videos.com/video321/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Прикольный мулт...Смотрел...

Comment: @Геннадий Журов Отлично (+) Больше одного плюса поставить не смогу.Приглашаю вас в чат по svg/ Обсуждаем не только svg, но и многое другое. Активность чата возникает обычно вечерами https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , спасибо. Правда по теме `svg` я вряд ли там кого-то удивлю. ))

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров А такой задачи и не стоит, удивлять кого-то Будем вместе изучать svg, обмениваясь приемами, техниками, ответами на конкретные  примеры

Comment: У меня виден только белый экран.

Comment: @MindCleaner , какой браузер?

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров firefox 58.0.1 на lubuntu

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров у меня плагин Cisco отключен, может из-за этого.

Comment: @MindCleaner , признаться честно - не знаю, не специалист. Думал может старый браузер, не поддерживающий html5

Answer (score 7):

Вариант на `SVG` с использованием `<animate attributeName="opacity"/>`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1776 943">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkEWk.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  <image class="slide" xlink:href="http://v-georgia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/IMAG2635.jpg" x="485" y="209" width="25%" height="20%">
    <animate id="for" attributeName="opacity" begin="first.end" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" fill="freeze"/>
  </image>
  <image class="slide" xlink:href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01816/nice-negresco_1816701b.jpg" x="485" y="209" width="25%" height="20%">
    <animate id="first" attributeName="opacity" begin="second.end" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" fill="default"/>
  </image>
  <image class="slide" xlink:href="http://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/420256-new-york-wallpaper-full-hd.jpg" x="485" y="209" width="25%" height="20%">
    <animate id="second" attributeName="opacity" begin="third.end" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" fill="default"/>
  </image>
  <image class="slide" xlink:href="https://forbes.kz/img/articles/99661f12e332c908c2a3a754d3f4942b-big.jpg" x="485" y="209" width="25%" height="20%">
    <animate id="third" attributeName="opacity" begin="fourth.end" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" fill="default"/>
  </image>
  <image class="slide" xlink:href="http://fanoboi.com/city/10/city-by-the-sea-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg" x="485" y="209" width="25%" height="20%">
    <animate id="fourth" attributeName="opacity" begin="0s;for.end" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" fill="default"/>
  </image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Хотел бы предложить адаптивный вариант с автозаполнением прозрачных пикселей подгружаемым видео.

> Укажите картинку с заранее вырезанным контейнером чтобы пиксели были
> прозрачными и туда поместится видео.

Использовал:

- [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas)
- [drawImage (canvas)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)
- [getImageData (canvas)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)
- [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```js
const imageUrl = 'https://i.imgur.com/o9YdVPR.png';
const videoUrl = 'https://i.imgur.com/H7KnCdV.mp4';
const insertPaddings = 2;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const img = new Image();
img.src = imageUrl;
img.crossOrigin = `Anonymous`;

const video = document.createElement('video');

img.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  const transparentPixels = [];
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
      const index = (y * canvas.width + x) * 4;
      const alpha = imageData.data[index + 3];
      if (alpha < 255) {
        transparentPixels.push({ x, y });
      }
    }
  }

    const { x: x1, y: y1 } = transparentPixels[0];
    const { x: x2, y: y2 } = transparentPixels[transparentPixels.length - 1];
  
  const width = x2 - x1;
  const height = y2 - y1;

  video.src = videoUrl;
  video.crossOrigin = `Anonymous`;
  video.muted = true;
  video.autoplay = true;
  video.loop = true;
  video.play();
  
  drawVideo(
    x1 - insertPaddings,
    y1 - insertPaddings,
    width + insertPaddings * 2,
    height + insertPaddings * 2,
  )
};

function drawVideo(x, y, width, height) {
    const loop = () => {
    if (!video.paused && !video.ended) {
      ctx.drawImage(video, x, y, width, height);
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
  }
  loop();
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```